# configure properly my filter class in web.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm working on web app maven project, i need a Filter class which implements javax.servlet.Filter.
SO i can't configure it properly in my web.xml. I get " 'filter.RestrictionFilter' is not assignable to 'javax.servlet.Filter'" error can someone help me to resolve it:

this is my filter class:

```js
package filter;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Filter;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;


//@WebFilter("/RestrictionFilter")
public  class RestrictionFilter implements Filter {
   //constructor
    public RestrictionFilter(){

   }


  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException{

  }


  public void destroy(){

  }


  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                       FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException,ServletException{

        //cast des objets req et res

      HttpServletRequest request =(HttpServletRequest) req;
      HttpServletResponse response =(HttpServletResponse)res;

      //recuperation de la session depuis la requete
      HttpSession session=request.getSession();

      //session de l'utilisateur
      String usersession=(String)session.getAttribute("userSession");


      if(usersession==null){
          //aucun utilisateur connecté donc retour vers la page de connexion
          request.getRequestDispatcher("/m1if03").forward(request,response);


      }else{ //affichage de la page restreinte
          filterChain.doFilter(request,response);

      }
  }



    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord logRecord) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

this is my configuration in web.xml file:

```js
<filter>
  <filter-name>RestrictionFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>filter.RestrictionFilter</filter-class>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>RestrictionFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/RestrictionFilter</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

i guess , i missed something, and don't know to resolve this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are implementing `java.util.logging.Filter`, not `javax.servlet.Filter`.  You need to implement the correct one.

Comment: I removed the import java.util.logging.Filter and this error vanished. thank u.